# How to allow users to build their own flatpages in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I have an app that allows users (admins actually) to add html to a model.  Then I serve that html on some page to other users (nonadmins).  I would like to allow the admins to create arbitrary html on these pages, *including adding images*.  I don't want the admins to have to jump through hoops to get their content into this html field.  Suppose a user has some images on their local machine that they want to go into this html field they are creating.  I want it to be super brain-dead easy for them to get those images in there.

Right now I just have a model with an html field and I provide a [WYSIWYG editor](https://github.com/pydanny/django-wysiwyg) .  On a page that users can see, I just load that model.html (filter it as safe) and display.  But if the admin user wants to add an image, they still have to figure out hosting and linking in their html document.

Is there a way to use Django flatpages + static to achieve this? Or some kind of app that provides a wordpress-like editor inside Django?

Comment: You can try django-filer (https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer), but "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I would recommend just installing [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/). It does exactly what you want and is the most lightweight, simple and Wordpress like of the Django CMSs. It integrates TinyMCE and Django filebrowser like you want and you can throw away the bits you don't want. This is almost definitely the quickest way to do what you want.